# Setting inURL data attribute using jquery.dfp.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-dfp

I am trying to set the inURL parameter for each ad using the JQuery plugin library: https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js

```
        <div class="adunit" data-adunit="Ad_Unit_1_Name" data-dimensions="728x90" data-targeting='{"inURL":"Some_Unique_Val_1"}'></div>
        <div class="adunit" data-adunit="Ad_Unit_2_Name" data-dimensions="300x250" data-targeting='{"inURL":"Some_Unique_Val_2"}'></div>
```

Unfortunately the above doesn't work and stores the data into the 'prev_scp' query parameter. Looking at the request it needs to go into the 'cust_params'. I looked at the library's source
and it doesn't seem possible but maybe I overlooked something. Anyone know how?

---

In response to Matt Cooper (Aug. 30, 2013):

As you know, the 'inURL' parameter is changeable at the service level by passing in {setTargeting:{inURL:'Some_Unique_Val'}} as the options object when calling '$.dfp'. Unfortunately, it is not changeable at the ad unit level from your plug-in.

One of the reasons being is that the 'dfpOptions' is set after the ad units are created in the createAds method. I am going to modify it to see if I can make it work at the ad unit level.

Now is it correct to modify 'inURL', from my understanding:

https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1650154#setTargetingUn

it is there as a user defined variable and the company I am working for is using that part for further identification, hence my wanting to be able to do it.

Comment: Ok I think I get it now... pretty sure that will be a problem with the google script though... have you tried doing it with the native code and without my plugin? Let me know if you come up with a solution and I will integrate it into the plugin as well.

Answer (score 0):

That is my plugin. I think what is going on here is you are using it slightly wrong... inURL is set automatically by the plugin so you should not being trying to override it like you are... it is just there to send through all of the URL segments of the current URL so that you can match a section of your site or multiple sections.

If you are trying to set targeting info for each ad unit then I suggest using a different keyword and then setting up that same keyword in DFP - by the way you need to have made sure you set up the keywords in DFP as well otherwise they will not work.

If you have any more questions or a more specific example of what is going wrong please feel free to let me know here or on github.

Comment: First, thank you for the plug-in. The less I deal with Google code, the better. :-)

I updated the post above in response to this post as StackOverflow was complaining about too many characters in this comment.